# Fetched data is null using Express API on localhost:3001

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using `useEffect` and `useStat`e with fetch to obtain a JSON array and render in React. I follow an example of grocery objects at localhost:3333/list that's implemented with `json-server`. This works! I then switch to my express API localhost:3001/peeps which also has id and name values (no rendering code change needed) and I get Fetch error. The `data` value is null. In the terminal window for the running API it shows the output JSON (logged). The fetch makes the call but the react app get's nothing.

Points of interest:

- I've added Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
- The sample json-server API has a delay in response, my API does not.

I'm totally stumped. I started with a complex react app and now I've been working backwards and towards simplicity. I've had no luck for 2 days now and I've tried everything I think.

My Express API Controller (tested in Postman successfully)

```js
// Retrieve all Peeps from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Peep.getAll((err, data) => {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving peeps."
            });
        else {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.send(data);
    }
        
    });
};
```

My App.js where I'm trying to render

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { getList } from './services/list';

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    getList()
      .then(items => {
        if(mounted) {
          setList(items)
        }
      })
    return () => mounted = false;
  }, [])

  alert(list);

  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>My List</h1>
     <ul>
       {list.map(item => <li key={item.item}>{item.item}</li>)}
     </ul>
   </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues with your code.

- You don't need a `mounted` variable. The useffect with empty array `[]` as second parameter will only render once so you don't need another variable to keep track of it.
- The then function provides a `response` object in which there's a field called `data`. Inside the `data` field will be the data you will get from the server.

Assuming the response from the server in the below format:

```
{
 items:[{item:"Item #1"},{item:"Item #2"},{item:"Item #3"},{item:"Item #4"}]
}
```

We can get the list of items as `response.data.items` as shown below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { getList } from './services/list';

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getList()
      .then(response => {
          setList(response.data.items)
      })
  }, [])

  alert(list);

  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>My List</h1>
     <ul>
       {list.map(item => <li key={item.item}>{item.item}</li>)}
     </ul>
   </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I hope it helps